# how to handle small go projects on google cloud - what is the preferred infra/CI setup

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration

**Introduction**

I am new here, after a long break from coding, I decided to do a new pet project. 
So here I am with the new language and new technologies behind it.

I have an application that writes data from Twitter to file. It is a streamer and the file is closed on a daily basis (midnight) and another one is open.

I have another application that works with these files (00:01) and creates a histogram based on data from this file (day-1), data from the binance API and google semantic analysis.

**My current approach is:**

1. The repository is in bitbucket
2. I have a running machine on google cloud (vm instance)
3. I am downloading the repository manually from the bitbucket to the VM
4. I am unpacking the repo and running the code there

Questions:

1. How should I automate/Continous integrate it? (what are the best practice for pet projects)
2. As I am only working on API/Files should I use something different than the VM?

Comment: Given it's a personal project, I'd suggest at least giving thought to using the App Engine Standard environment with the Go 1.11 beta. Note that 
this would require you to write your file to a Cloud Storage bucket, as you don't have regular file read/write access on this platform, but that isn't a huge change. https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/go-1-11-is-now-available-on-app-engine

Comment: Interesting! Will read more for sure! :) Thank you